# Onde colocar o backend pesado usando .NET5?

Tags: .net, mvc

Bom dia. Estou começando a trabalhar com o .NET5 e estou com umas dúvidas.
Um exemplo de funcionalidade da minha aplicação: 
**VALIDADOR DE ARQUIVO**
*Recebo um arquivo txt que é um arquivo de implantação separado por ponto e vírgula onde cada campinho tem uma função. Pego cada campinho desse, valido e de acordo com as regras do meu negócio e jogo todo resultado numa tabela.*

Sei que minha tabela fica na view, que cada campo eu estruturo na model e que a controller faz a ligação entre a model e a view, mas não sei onde fazer o backend pesado, com minhas regras de negócio, IF´s de validação do negócio, até mesmo o recebimento do arquivo e particionamento em campos.

Li sobre multicamadas, utilizar a camada de negócio. Mas... é realmente necessário?
Não é uma aplicação extremamente grande. Tem como "fugir" da utilização da multicamadas? Sendo assim, onde entraria esse back?

Comment: olá Carol, sua pegunta está muito ampla e subjetiva, ela pode ser fechada por ser sujeita a opiniões diversas e não uma resposta mais objetiva, tente reduziar mais a um problema só e mais especifico.

A ideia de camadas não é pra deixar organizado apenas, mas separar as responsabilidades. Entenda que as camadas não necessariamente precisam ser projetos diferentes, mas tem de ser separadas em classes específicas, de forma que cada classe faça algo específico, e tentar separá-las por interfaces, para que sejam facilmente testáveis, tente olhar por esse aspecto

Comment: pense por exemplo que numa casa tivesse o sofá no banheiro, ou uma banheira na cozinha... propositos errados, lugares errados, as coisas estão separadas e agrupadas nos lugares que fazem sentido, o código numa forma muito simplista é a mesma coisa :)

Comment: pra não escrever muito mas ir no ponto das "regas de negócio"... se colocar tudo junto com a interface e código do banco... imagina que amanhã muda o banco dados, ou seu código vai pra nuvem, ou ainda muda a interface, de web pra mobile, imagina a bagunça de mexer em todo o código... se a interface, os modelos, as regras de negocio e a parte de banco de dados estiverem separadas, é muito fácil mudar cada parte individualmente, por isso se separa em camadas :)

Comment: Obrigada Ricardo. Seu exemplo já me ajudou!
É difícil uma pergunta mais específica, pq eu realmente estava bem perdida.
Queria entender primeiro a dor de colocar tudo junto e saber se era ou não um pensamento válido.

Comment: se estiver estando sobre isso, o tal "tudo junto" constumam chamar de monolítico.. tem um conceito não só sobre camadas, mas como separação de negócio, microserviçoes etc, mas se olhar monolítico vai ver muitas razões pelas quais se separam as coisas :)

Comment: A model se chama model porque é a camada lógica do **modelo do domínio**, isto é, da representação do problema de negócio que a sua aplicação se propõe a resolver. Então o que deve ir para o modelo são regras de negócio independentes da interface, e que interagem com a camada de acesso a dados (leitura e escrita de arquivos, acesso a banco). Estou falando de **arquitetura em camadas** (_layered architecture_).  Entre a interface e o modelo tem a camada de aplicação. Ela pode oferecer para a interface por exemplo os serviços de upload de arquivo e processamento de arquivo.